# I get a UnauthorizedAccessException even when running my winforms app with administrator privileges?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm trying to use a streamWriter to write to a file in a specified directory, but I keep getting UnauthorizedAccessException. I ran the .exe file with admininistrator privileges(AP), as well as trying to run Visual Studio itself with AP, to no effect. I don't think there's much relevant code here, except for this:

```
try
{
    System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputPath);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please run the app with administrator privileges.\n" + uae.Message);
    Close();
}
```

The message box keeps popping up no matter what I do.

Comment: What are `outputPath` and `uae.Message`?

Comment: @BACON outputPath is a string of the output path for the generated file. uae.Message is a System message associated with the UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: When posting a question here you can generally assume that respondents already know the basics, at the least, of the subject matter and are trying to provide help, not receive it themselves.  I was asking what those _values_ are because they could be significant to your problem.

Comment: @BACON outputpath is C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\PIN_images\ and im not sure how to determine the value of uae

Comment: The debugger would be the best way to inspect and copy properties from `uae`, but you're also displaying `Message` in your message box.  Your problem, though, appears to be that you're attempting to instantiate a `StreamWriter` using the path of a(n existing) _directory_ (`PIN_images`), whereas you need to pass it the path of a _file_ (existing or not).